# Black screen and blinking cursor on boot

Tags: 10.10, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I'm having trouble booting into Ubuntu 10.10 on my laptop. When I turn it on, I get the BIOS menu and then nothing but a black screen with a blinking text cursor at the top. I was able to boot from the CD, but can't my system back up. Any ideas?

I don't see anything at all except for the BIOS splash. I don't have a grub menu, but if I hold down shift while rebooting, when I let go, "GRUB" appears at the top left corner, but then nothing happens.

It's a System76 Pangolin laptop

```
   Display Resolution 15.6" HD+ LED Display with Super Glossy Surface (1600 x 900)
   Graphics ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4570 Graphics with 512MB GDDR2 Memory
   Hard Drive 320 GB 7200 RPM SATA II
   Memory 4 GB – DDR3 1066 MHZ 2 DIMMs
   Optical Drive CD-RW / DVD-RW
   Processor Core i7-620M Processor ( 32nm, 4MB L3 Cache, 2.66GHz / 3.33GHz Turbo Mode )
   Wireless 802.11 B+G+N Wireless LAN Module
```