# Blank screen with blinking cursor after install

Tags: installation, boot, grub2

I find that sometimes when I install Ubuntu 11, I get a blank screen with a blinking cursor... what's wrong?

Following **[this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2622/blank-screen-blinking-cursor-on-boot)**

- Press shift during boot
- `e` to edit entry (`quiet splash` to `text`)
- `F10` to boot
- got black screen without cursor

Then tried from **[another answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6656/black-screen-and-blinking-cursor-on-boot/6743#6743)**

- replace `quiet splash` to `xforcevesa` (what does this do?)
- got same blank screen without cursor

Then I tried boot into recovery, then update GRUB entries. That works, but when I restart, I'm back to square one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try editing the boot entry and placing "nomodeset" (without the quotes) as an option.

Comment: ok, so thats works somewhat but I get http://i.imgur.com/3SysE.png

Comment: Also, I notice that once I install a GUI (lxde lxdm xserver-xorg) it boots ok. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I too had this blank screen issue for my encrypted LVM setup.  I found out that grub was installed on my usb installation drive instead of my hard disk.  After re-installing grub onto my disk, I no longer get the blank screen.  See my adventures [here](http://blog.nguyenvq.com/2011/09/15/backup-re-install-ubuntu-with-full-disk-encryption-and-restore-all-files-and-settings/).