# Just Installed a CLI system then ubuntu-desktop, does not boot automatically

Tags: installation, 11.10, grub2

I installed a CLI system with Ubuntu 11.10 Beta 2 Alternate CD. Then installed Ubuntu Desktop (--no-install-recommends). After a restart, it hangs at the below screen

[image]

Whats wrong?

Btw: I notice a CLI system will NOT boot in by default (even in 11.04), I must go recovery mode and update grub then resume boot. This happens even when there are GRUB entries for the OSes already (though I am not sure if they are invalid or something). [Another method is setting `nomodeset`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44374/blank-screen-with-blinking-cursor-after-install)

**UPDATE**

I used edited the boot entry to include `text nomodeset`. Then I got a full log with 1 fail

[image]

Maybe I missed a package since I installed Ubuntu Desktop with `no-install-recommends`

**UPDATE 2: With Ubuntu 11.10 Stable**

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 Stable (CLI System) then installed `ubuntu-desktop --no-install-recommends`. `startx` to boot into Ubuntu Desktop OK. but reboot and got stuck on the above screen

Tried: Boot into recovery, Update GRUB, Resume got:

[image]

Tried booting into Ubuntu 11.10 but with `text nomodeset` in GRUB got similar as above

[image]

Comment: please paste all this command -> What does `sudo fdisk -l` show?, paste your `fstab` and execute `sudo blkid`...

Comment: also `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hm.  From those screenshots it looks like the display manager (`LightDM`) thinks it's starting but is not switching VT properly (or possibly not starting properly at all).  It's not clear whether you've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to switch to the VT that lightdm will be starting on.

The logs in `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` might be helpful in working out what's happening.  **Note**: these may contain some identifying information, like your local username.

It's possible that either installing `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo` or adding `vt.handoff=7` to your grub kernel boot commandline would fix this.

Either way, this looks like you might have hit a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try booting with the `noacpi` option, as well as both `noacpi` and `nomodeset`. There seems to be something about the ACPI initialization that gets in the way of (even text mode) video. On a related note, I had to start the 11.10 installer in `noacpi`  mode on my Thinkpad T420s to get it to start up properly, but after install everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get all the [OK] can you just try to do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an ACPI issue, but there are many steps to troubleshooting this properly. Take a look at the following wiki page and go through the steps.

> https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingACPI

This is a blog entry about what I had to do with my daughter's machine:

> http://ftbeowulf.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/oneiric-gone-wrong/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 11.10 server after installing `ubuntu-desktop` with the `--no-install-recommends` flag.

I solved it with:

```
apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter
```