# What are the implications of --no-install-recommends (apt-get install)?

Tags: apt, software-installation

When I install packages using `--no-install-recommends`, can I say only packages listed [here (Ubuntu Package Search)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/ubuntu-desktop) as "depends" are installed?

I ask because I suspect [some problems with boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65079/11-10-just-installed-a-cli-system-then-ubuntu-desktop-does-not-boot-automaticall) might be caused by some packages not being installed. Some time back, I also had problems with Wireless Drivers and seemed to be missing something.

Comment: The first link here appears to be broken :/

Answer (score 146, accepted):

That's correct. By default, Ubuntu installs recommended but not suggested packages. With `--no-install-recommends`, only the main dependencies (packages in the `Depends` field) are installed.

Comment: Since installing using `--in-install-recommends` leads to problems ([boot up in my case](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65079/just-installed-a-cli-system-then-ubuntu-desktop-does-not-boot-automatically)), if I install the Full Ubuntu Desktop then remove Applications (recommends & suggests) I don't need it should give the same result as doing it from a CLI system? Would there be any clutter/un-used applications left behind? If I use software center I suppose there will be things left behind?

Comment: Installing with `--no-install-recommends` vs. removing packages afterwards is not the same. The first skips *all* recommended packages where in the second case, some packages may still be installed (as dependency of another package). I suggest you using the Alternate installer which allows you to select packages you want to install.

Comment: if I do a `autoremove` afterwards, I will still not have a similar result I suppose?

Comment: `autoremove` only removes packages which are marked "auto" with no packages depending on them, so no, you won't get a similar result.