# What is installed by default that can be removed?

Tags: disk-usage

I am using a computer with a very strict space limit - less than 1000MB. For various reasons, I have the 2GB needed to install it, but I now need to shrink it down as much as I can.

For that reason, I've [listed all the packages sorted by size](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14545598/), but I am not sure what I can remove safely.

Is there anything that can go?

Comment: It's a bit broad / primarily opinion-based, as long as I have a shell, `coreutils`, a package manager and networking I'd call it an OS :). Maybe you should start fresh with Ubuntu Server (~600MB)?

Comment: @kos hmm, I need GUI (this is installed simply for inkscape) It started at about 650, I've made it 800 with inkscape so I'm trying to cut it down :P

Comment: Hmmm Lubuntu Desktop 15.10 is ~780MB.

Comment: You could get the minimal installation iso, install a GUI and Inkscape. Much less than 2 GB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question would be too long and broad to answer; on the other hand, uninstalling random packages is not really a good idea.

What you should do instead is (as suggested in the comments) perform a clean reinstall with a minimal ISO and select only the GUI amongst the packages to include (plus Inkscape, since you need it).

Comment: Did this about 10 minutes ago!

Answer (score 2):

A good choice is to do a fresh [Ubuntu Server-based](https://www.ubuntu.com/server) install, because it's robust and minimal. Consider not to install LAMP, if it's not the purpose.

After that,

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends lubuntu-desktop
```

or

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends xubuntu-desktop
```

So [you won't install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65081/what-are-the-implications-of-no-install-recommends-apt-get-install) all stuff that normally comes with full install.