# What does the --no-install-recommends flag do exactly?

Tags: apt

As far as I know, typing "apt install some-package" installs the package, dependecies and recommended packages. Would I be using the --no-install-recommends flag, then only the package and its dependencies would be installed.

However, I found out that the list of recommended packages changes when the --no-install-recommends flag is used. I want to know why this happens, because I think this behaviour does not make sense for this flag.

This is different from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65081/what-are-the-implications-of-no-install-recommends-apt-get-install) because I want to know why the list recommended packages changes.

```
:~$ sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  accountwizard akonadi-backend-mysql akonadi-server akregator amarok amarok-common amarok-utils apport-kde apt-xapian-index apturl-kde ark baloo-kf5 baloo-utils bluedevil breeze breeze-cursor-theme catdoc cdparanoia
  cdrdao cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin debconf-kde-data discover discover-data dmsetup dolphin dragonplayer dvd+rw-tools fonts-noto fonts-noto-hinted fonts-noto-mono fonts-noto-unhinted fonts-oxygen frameworkintegration
  freerdp-x11 gpgsm growisofs gstreamer-qapt gstreamer1.0-nice gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk2-engines-pixbuf gtk3-engines-breeze gwenview ibus-qt4 ieee-data k3b k3b-data kaccounts-integration kaccounts-providers
  kaddressbook kamera kate kate5-data kcalc kde-baseapps-bin kde-baseapps-data kde-cli-tools kde-cli-tools-data kde-config-gtk-style kde-config-gtk-style-preview kde-config-mailtransport kde-config-screenlocker
  kde-config-sddm kde-config-telepathy-accounts kde-config-whoopsie kde-spectacle kde-style-oxygen-qt5 kde-style-qtcurve-qt4 kde-style-qtcurve-qt5 kde-telepathy kde-telepathy-approver kde-telepathy-auth-handler
  kde-telepathy-contact-list kde-telepathy-data kde-telepathy-desktop-applets kde-telepathy-filetransfer-handler kde-telepathy-integration-module kde-telepathy-kaccounts kde-telepathy-kpeople kde-telepathy-minimal
  kde-telepathy-send-file kde-telepathy-text-ui kdeconnect kdeconnect-plasma kded5 kdegraphics-strigi-analyzer kdemultimedia-kio-plugins kdenetwork-filesharing kdepim-doc kdepim-runtime kdepimlibs-data
  kdepimlibs-kio-plugins kdeplasma-addons-data kdesudo kdoctools5 kgamma5 khelpcenter khotkeys khotkeys-data kimageformat-plugins kinfocenter kinit kio kio-audiocd kio-extras kio-extras-data kio-mtp kmail kmenuedit
  knotes konsole konsole-kpart kontact konversation konversation-data korganizer krdc kross kscreen ksshaskpass ksysguard ksysguard-data ksysguardd ksystemlog ktexteditor-data ktexteditor-katepart ktnef ktorrent
  ktorrent-data kubuntu-driver-manager kubuntu-notification-helper kubuntu-settings-desktop kubuntu-web-shortcuts kwalletmanager kwin kwin-addons kwin-common kwin-data kwin-style-breeze kwin-x11 kwrited libaio1
  libakonadi-kmime4 libappstreamqt1 libavahi-gobject0 libbaloocore4 libbaloofiles4 libbalooxapian4 libboost-thread1.58.0 libc-ares2 libchm1 libcln6 libdebconf-kde1 libdiscover2 libdmtx0a libdolphinvcs5 libepub0
  libfakekey0 libfarstream-0.2-5 libflac++6v5 libfreerdp-rail1.1 libgps22 libgrantlee-templates5 libgrantlee-textdocument5 libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 libhsqldb1.8.0-java libibus-qt1 libiso9660-8 libjs-underscore libk3b6
  libk3b6-extracodecs libkaccounts1 libkcddb4 libkcompactdisc4 libkdecorations2-5v5 libkdecorations2private5v5 libkexiv2-11v5 libkexiv2-data libkf5activitiesexperimentalstats1 libkf5akonadiagentbase5
  libkf5akonadicalendar5 libkf5akonadicontact5 libkf5akonadicore-bin libkf5akonadicore5 libkf5akonadimime5 libkf5akonadinotes5 libkf5akonadiprivate5 libkf5akonadisearchdebug5 libkf5akonadisearchpim5
  libkf5akonadiwidgets5 libkf5alarmcalendar5 libkf5baloo5 libkf5balooengine5 libkf5baloowidgets-bin libkf5baloowidgets5 libkf5bluezqt-data libkf5bluezqt6 libkf5bookmarks-data libkf5bookmarks5 libkf5calendarcore5
  libkf5calendarsupport5 libkf5calendarutils5 libkf5contacts-data libkf5contacts5 libkf5dnssd-data libkf5dnssd5 libkf5emoticons-bin libkf5emoticons-data libkf5emoticons5 libkf5eventviews5 libkf5filemetadata-bin
  libkf5filemetadata-data libkf5filemetadata3 libkf5followupreminder5 libkf5gapi-data libkf5gapicalendar5 libkf5gapicontacts5 libkf5gapicore5 libkf5gapidrive5 libkf5gapitasks5 libkf5gpgmepp-pthread5 libkf5gpgmepp5
  libkf5gravatar5 libkf5holidays-data libkf5holidays5 libkf5identitymanagement5 libkf5imap5 libkf5incidenceeditorsng5 libkf5itemmodels5 libkf5js5 libkf5jsembed-data libkf5jsembed5 libkf5kcmutils-data libkf5kcmutils5
  libkf5kdcraw5 libkf5kdelibs4support-data libkf5kdelibs4support5 libkf5kdelibs4support5-bin libkf5kdepimdbusinterfaces5 libkf5kdgantt2-5 libkf5khtml-bin libkf5khtml-data libkf5khtml5 libkf5kiofilewidgets5
  libkf5kiontlm5 libkf5kipi-data libkf5kipi30.0.0 libkf5kmanagesieve5 libkf5kontactinterface-data libkf5kontactinterface5 libkf5krosscore5 libkf5krossui5 libkf5ksieve5 libkf5ksieveui5 libkf5ldap5 libkf5libkdepim5
  libkf5libkleo5 libkf5mailcommon5 libkf5mailimporter5 libkf5mailtransport-data libkf5mailtransport5 libkf5mbox5 libkf5messagecomposer5 libkf5messagecore5 libkf5messagelist5 libkf5messageviewer5 libkf5mime5
  libkf5modemmanagerqt6 libkf5networkmanagerqt6 libkf5newstuff-data libkf5newstuff5 libkf5noteshared5 libkf5notifyconfig-data libkf5notifyconfig5 libkf5parts-data libkf5parts-plugins libkf5parts5 libkf5people-data
  libkf5people5 libkf5peoplebackend5 libkf5peoplewidgets5 libkf5pimcommon5 libkf5pimtextedit5 libkf5prison1 libkf5pty-data libkf5pty5 libkf5qgpgme5 libkf5runner5 libkf5screen-bin libkf5screen6 libkf5sendlater5
  libkf5solid5 libkf5solid5-data libkf5su-bin libkf5su-data libkf5su5 libkf5syndication5 libkf5sysguard-bin libkf5sysguard-data libkf5templateparser5 libkf5texteditor5 libkf5texteditor5-libjs-underscore
  libkf5threadweaver5 libkf5tnef5 libkf5unitconversion-data libkf5unitconversion5 libkf5wallet-bin libkf5wallet-data libkf5wallet5 libkf5waylandserver5 libkf5webkit5 libkf5xmlrpcclient-data libkf5xmlrpcclient5
  libkfilemetadata4 libkfontinst5 libkfontinstui5 libkidletime4 libkmime4 libknewstuff2-4 libkolab1 libkolabxml1v5 libkonq-common libkonq5-templates libkpimutils4 libkprintutils4 libksane-data libksane0
  libkscreenlocker5 libksgrd7 libksignalplotter7 libktorrent-l10n libktorrent5 libktpcommoninternals9 libktplogger9 libktpmodels9 libktpotr9 libktpwidgets9 libkubuntu1 libkwalletbackend5-5 libkwin4-effect-builtins1
  libkwineffects7 libkwinglutils7 libkwinxrenderutils7 libkworkspace5-5 liblastfm1 liblmdb0 libloudmouth1-0 libmeanwhile1 libmpcdec6 libmusicbrainz5cc2v5 libmygpo-qt1 libnice10 libokularcore7 libotr5 liboxygenstyle5-5
  liboxygenstyleconfig5-5 libpackagekitqt5-0 libpam-kwallet4 libpam-kwallet5 libparted-fs-resize0 libperl4-corelibs-perl libplasma-geolocation-interface5 libpoppler-qt4-4 libpoppler-qt5-1 libpowerdevilcore2
  libpowerdevilui5 libprocesscore7 libprocessui7 libpurple-bin libpurple0 libqalculate5-data libqalculate5v5 libqapt3 libqapt3-runtime libqca-qt5-2 libqca-qt5-2-plugins libqgsttools-p1 libqimageblitz4 libqmobipocket1
  libqrencode3 libqt4-help libqt4-scripttools libqt4-test libqt5clucene5 libqt5concurrent5 libqt5designer5 libqt5designercomponents5 libqt5help5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimediaquick-p5
  libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5qml-graphicaleffects libqt5sql5-mysql libqt5xmlpatterns5 libqtassistantclient4 libqtcurve-utils2 libqtscript4-core libqtscript4-gui libqtscript4-network libqtscript4-sql
  libqtscript4-uitools libqtscript4-xml libreoffice-base libreoffice-base-drivers libreoffice-java-common libreoffice-kde libreoffice-sdbc-firebird libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb libreoffice-style-oxygen
  libreoffice-style-tango libscim8v5 libsyndication4 libtag-extras1 libtaskmanager5 libtelepathy-logger-qt5 libtelepathy-qt4-2 libtelepathy-qt5-0 libvcdinfo0 libweather-ion7 libxapian-1.3-5 libxcb-cursor0 libxcb-dpms0
  libxcb-record0 libxerces-c3.1 libxfreerdp-client1.1 libzephyr4 libzip4 milou muon-notifier muon-updater mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7 ofono okular okular-extra-backends oxygen-sounds p7zip-full
  partitionmanager phonon4qt5-backend-gstreamer pidgin-data pinentry-qt plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-desktop plasma-desktop-data plasma-discover plasma-discover-common plasma-discover-private
  plasma-discover-updater plasma-look-and-feel-org-kde-breezedark-desktop plasma-nm plasma-pa plasma-runners-addons plasma-wallpapers-addons plasma-widgets-addons plasma-workspace plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo
  plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text polkit-kde-agent-1 powerdevil powerdevil-data print-manager python-qt4-dbus python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 python3-pykde4 python3-pyqt4 python3-pyqt5 python3-sip python3-xapian1.3 qapt-batch
  qapt-deb-installer qdbus-qt5 qml-module-org-kde-bluezqt qml-module-org-kde-draganddrop qml-module-org-kde-extensionplugin qml-module-org-kde-kcoreaddons qml-module-org-kde-kio qml-module-org-kde-kwindowsystem
  qml-module-org-kde-runnermodel qml-module-org-kde-solid qml-module-org-kde-telepathy qml-module-qtmultimedia qml-module-qtquick-controls-styles-breeze qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel qml-module-qtwebkit
  qt5-image-formats-plugins qtdeclarative5-xmllistmodel-plugin qttools5-dev-tools sddm sddm-theme-breeze signon-kwallet-extension skanlite socat software-properties-kde sshfs systemsettings telepathy-accounts-signon
  telepathy-gabble telepathy-haze telepathy-logger telepathy-ring telepathy-salut ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt user-manager vcdimager wodim
Suggested packages:
  akonadi-backend-postgresql akonadi-backend-sqlite amarok-doc libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-sql-psql moodbar rar unrar | unrar-free orion-gtk-theme keyutils dolphin-plugins cdrskin k3b-extrathemes k3b-i18n normalize-audio
  movixmaker-2 kde-config-cddb gtk2-engines-qtcurve telepathy-idle telepathy-rakia lame clamav kleopatra procmail spamassassin | bogofilter | spambayes | bsfilter | crm114 gnokii krfb krosspython pi gpsd
  java-virtual-machine libhsqldb1.8.0-java-gcj libotr5-bin libparted-dev libreoffice-gcj libreoffice-report-builder unixodbc libjtds-java libreoffice-mysql-connector | libmyodbc | libmysql-java
  libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql | odbc-postgresql | libpg-java libsqliteodbc | tdsodbc | mdbtools konqueror kde-icons-oxygen oxygencursors tango-icon-theme xapian-tools jovie unrar p7zip-rar hfsplus hfsutils jfsutils
  reiser4progs reiserfsprogs xfsprogs pinentry-doc network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openvpn network-manager-vpnc python3-pyqt4-dbg python3-pyqt5-dbg xapian-doc skanlite-dbg cdrkit-doc
Recommended packages:
  kdepim-themeditors kdepimlibs-bin plasma-discover-notifier system-config-printer
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  accountwizard akonadi-backend-mysql akonadi-server akregator amarok amarok-common amarok-utils apport-kde apt-xapian-index apturl-kde ark baloo-kf5 baloo-utils bluedevil breeze breeze-cursor-theme catdoc cdparanoia
  cdrdao cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin debconf-kde-data discover discover-data dmsetup dolphin dragonplayer dvd+rw-tools fonts-noto fonts-noto-hinted fonts-noto-mono fonts-noto-unhinted fonts-oxygen frameworkintegration
  freerdp-x11 gpgsm growisofs gstreamer-qapt gstreamer1.0-nice gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk2-engines-pixbuf gtk3-engines-breeze gwenview ibus-qt4 ieee-data k3b k3b-data kaccounts-integration kaccounts-providers
  kaddressbook kamera kate kate5-data kcalc kde-baseapps-bin kde-baseapps-data kde-cli-tools kde-cli-tools-data kde-config-gtk-style kde-config-gtk-style-preview kde-config-mailtransport kde-config-screenlocker
  kde-config-sddm kde-config-telepathy-accounts kde-config-whoopsie kde-spectacle kde-style-oxygen-qt5 kde-style-qtcurve-qt4 kde-style-qtcurve-qt5 kde-telepathy kde-telepathy-approver kde-telepathy-auth-handler
  kde-telepathy-contact-list kde-telepathy-data kde-telepathy-desktop-applets kde-telepathy-filetransfer-handler kde-telepathy-integration-module kde-telepathy-kaccounts kde-telepathy-kpeople kde-telepathy-minimal
  kde-telepathy-send-file kde-telepathy-text-ui kdeconnect kdeconnect-plasma kded5 kdegraphics-strigi-analyzer kdemultimedia-kio-plugins kdenetwork-filesharing kdepim-doc kdepim-runtime kdepimlibs-data
  kdepimlibs-kio-plugins kdeplasma-addons-data kdesudo kdoctools5 kgamma5 khelpcenter khotkeys khotkeys-data kimageformat-plugins kinfocenter kinit kio kio-audiocd kio-extras kio-extras-data kio-mtp kmail kmenuedit
  knotes konsole konsole-kpart kontact konversation konversation-data korganizer krdc kross kscreen ksshaskpass ksysguard ksysguard-data ksysguardd ksystemlog ktexteditor-data ktexteditor-katepart ktnef ktorrent
  ktorrent-data kubuntu-desktop kubuntu-driver-manager kubuntu-notification-helper kubuntu-settings-desktop kubuntu-web-shortcuts kwalletmanager kwin kwin-addons kwin-common kwin-data kwin-style-breeze kwin-x11
  kwrited libaio1 libakonadi-kmime4 libappstreamqt1 libavahi-gobject0 libbaloocore4 libbaloofiles4 libbalooxapian4 libboost-thread1.58.0 libc-ares2 libchm1 libcln6 libdebconf-kde1 libdiscover2 libdmtx0a libdolphinvcs5
  libepub0 libfakekey0 libfarstream-0.2-5 libflac++6v5 libfreerdp-rail1.1 libgps22 libgrantlee-templates5 libgrantlee-textdocument5 libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 libhsqldb1.8.0-java libibus-qt1 libiso9660-8 libjs-underscore
  libk3b6 libk3b6-extracodecs libkaccounts1 libkcddb4 libkcompactdisc4 libkdecorations2-5v5 libkdecorations2private5v5 libkexiv2-11v5 libkexiv2-data libkf5activitiesexperimentalstats1 libkf5akonadiagentbase5
  libkf5akonadicalendar5 libkf5akonadicontact5 libkf5akonadicore-bin libkf5akonadicore5 libkf5akonadimime5 libkf5akonadinotes5 libkf5akonadiprivate5 libkf5akonadisearchdebug5 libkf5akonadisearchpim5
  libkf5akonadiwidgets5 libkf5alarmcalendar5 libkf5baloo5 libkf5balooengine5 libkf5baloowidgets-bin libkf5baloowidgets5 libkf5bluezqt-data libkf5bluezqt6 libkf5bookmarks-data libkf5bookmarks5 libkf5calendarcore5
  libkf5calendarsupport5 libkf5calendarutils5 libkf5contacts-data libkf5contacts5 libkf5dnssd-data libkf5dnssd5 libkf5emoticons-bin libkf5emoticons-data libkf5emoticons5 libkf5eventviews5 libkf5filemetadata-bin
  libkf5filemetadata-data libkf5filemetadata3 libkf5followupreminder5 libkf5gapi-data libkf5gapicalendar5 libkf5gapicontacts5 libkf5gapicore5 libkf5gapidrive5 libkf5gapitasks5 libkf5gpgmepp-pthread5 libkf5gpgmepp5
  libkf5gravatar5 libkf5holidays-data libkf5holidays5 libkf5identitymanagement5 libkf5imap5 libkf5incidenceeditorsng5 libkf5itemmodels5 libkf5js5 libkf5jsembed-data libkf5jsembed5 libkf5kcmutils-data libkf5kcmutils5
  libkf5kdcraw5 libkf5kdelibs4support-data libkf5kdelibs4support5 libkf5kdelibs4support5-bin libkf5kdepimdbusinterfaces5 libkf5kdgantt2-5 libkf5khtml-bin libkf5khtml-data libkf5khtml5 libkf5kiofilewidgets5
  libkf5kiontlm5 libkf5kipi-data libkf5kipi30.0.0 libkf5kmanagesieve5 libkf5kontactinterface-data libkf5kontactinterface5 libkf5krosscore5 libkf5krossui5 libkf5ksieve5 libkf5ksieveui5 libkf5ldap5 libkf5libkdepim5
  libkf5libkleo5 libkf5mailcommon5 libkf5mailimporter5 libkf5mailtransport-data libkf5mailtransport5 libkf5mbox5 libkf5messagecomposer5 libkf5messagecore5 libkf5messagelist5 libkf5messageviewer5 libkf5mime5
  libkf5modemmanagerqt6 libkf5networkmanagerqt6 libkf5newstuff-data libkf5newstuff5 libkf5noteshared5 libkf5notifyconfig-data libkf5notifyconfig5 libkf5parts-data libkf5parts-plugins libkf5parts5 libkf5people-data
  libkf5people5 libkf5peoplebackend5 libkf5peoplewidgets5 libkf5pimcommon5 libkf5pimtextedit5 libkf5prison1 libkf5pty-data libkf5pty5 libkf5qgpgme5 libkf5runner5 libkf5screen-bin libkf5screen6 libkf5sendlater5
  libkf5solid5 libkf5solid5-data libkf5su-bin libkf5su-data libkf5su5 libkf5syndication5 libkf5sysguard-bin libkf5sysguard-data libkf5templateparser5 libkf5texteditor5 libkf5texteditor5-libjs-underscore
  libkf5threadweaver5 libkf5tnef5 libkf5unitconversion-data libkf5unitconversion5 libkf5wallet-bin libkf5wallet-data libkf5wallet5 libkf5waylandserver5 libkf5webkit5 libkf5xmlrpcclient-data libkf5xmlrpcclient5
  libkfilemetadata4 libkfontinst5 libkfontinstui5 libkidletime4 libkmime4 libknewstuff2-4 libkolab1 libkolabxml1v5 libkonq-common libkonq5-templates libkpimutils4 libkprintutils4 libksane-data libksane0
  libkscreenlocker5 libksgrd7 libksignalplotter7 libktorrent-l10n libktorrent5 libktpcommoninternals9 libktplogger9 libktpmodels9 libktpotr9 libktpwidgets9 libkubuntu1 libkwalletbackend5-5 libkwin4-effect-builtins1
  libkwineffects7 libkwinglutils7 libkwinxrenderutils7 libkworkspace5-5 liblastfm1 liblmdb0 libloudmouth1-0 libmeanwhile1 libmpcdec6 libmusicbrainz5cc2v5 libmygpo-qt1 libnice10 libokularcore7 libotr5 liboxygenstyle5-5
  liboxygenstyleconfig5-5 libpackagekitqt5-0 libpam-kwallet4 libpam-kwallet5 libparted-fs-resize0 libperl4-corelibs-perl libplasma-geolocation-interface5 libpoppler-qt4-4 libpoppler-qt5-1 libpowerdevilcore2
  libpowerdevilui5 libprocesscore7 libprocessui7 libpurple-bin libpurple0 libqalculate5-data libqalculate5v5 libqapt3 libqapt3-runtime libqca-qt5-2 libqca-qt5-2-plugins libqgsttools-p1 libqimageblitz4 libqmobipocket1
  libqrencode3 libqt4-help libqt4-scripttools libqt4-test libqt5clucene5 libqt5concurrent5 libqt5designer5 libqt5designercomponents5 libqt5help5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimediaquick-p5
  libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5qml-graphicaleffects libqt5sql5-mysql libqt5xmlpatterns5 libqtassistantclient4 libqtcurve-utils2 libqtscript4-core libqtscript4-gui libqtscript4-network libqtscript4-sql
  libqtscript4-uitools libqtscript4-xml libreoffice-base libreoffice-base-drivers libreoffice-java-common libreoffice-kde libreoffice-sdbc-firebird libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb libreoffice-style-oxygen
  libreoffice-style-tango libscim8v5 libsyndication4 libtag-extras1 libtaskmanager5 libtelepathy-logger-qt5 libtelepathy-qt4-2 libtelepathy-qt5-0 libvcdinfo0 libweather-ion7 libxapian-1.3-5 libxcb-cursor0 libxcb-dpms0
  libxcb-record0 libxerces-c3.1 libxfreerdp-client1.1 libzephyr4 libzip4 milou muon-notifier muon-updater mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7 ofono okular okular-extra-backends oxygen-sounds p7zip-full
  partitionmanager phonon4qt5-backend-gstreamer pidgin-data pinentry-qt plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-desktop plasma-desktop-data plasma-discover plasma-discover-common plasma-discover-private
  plasma-discover-updater plasma-look-and-feel-org-kde-breezedark-desktop plasma-nm plasma-pa plasma-runners-addons plasma-wallpapers-addons plasma-widgets-addons plasma-workspace plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo
  plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text polkit-kde-agent-1 powerdevil powerdevil-data print-manager python-qt4-dbus python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 python3-pykde4 python3-pyqt4 python3-pyqt5 python3-sip python3-xapian1.3 qapt-batch
  qapt-deb-installer qdbus-qt5 qml-module-org-kde-bluezqt qml-module-org-kde-draganddrop qml-module-org-kde-extensionplugin qml-module-org-kde-kcoreaddons qml-module-org-kde-kio qml-module-org-kde-kwindowsystem
  qml-module-org-kde-runnermodel qml-module-org-kde-solid qml-module-org-kde-telepathy qml-module-qtmultimedia qml-module-qtquick-controls-styles-breeze qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel qml-module-qtwebkit
  qt5-image-formats-plugins qtdeclarative5-xmllistmodel-plugin qttools5-dev-tools sddm sddm-theme-breeze signon-kwallet-extension skanlite socat software-properties-kde sshfs systemsettings telepathy-accounts-signon
  telepathy-gabble telepathy-haze telepathy-logger telepathy-ring telepathy-salut ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt user-manager vcdimager wodim
0 upgraded, 506 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 225 MB of archives.
After this operation, 885 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n 
Abort.
```

```
:~$ sudo apt install --no-install-recommends kubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apt-xapian-index ark baloo-kf5 breeze breeze-cursor-theme dolphin fonts-noto-hinted frameworkintegration ieee-data kde-cli-tools kde-cli-tools-data kde-spectacle kded5 kdoctools5 khelpcenter khotkeys khotkeys-data
  kinfocenter kinit kio kio-extras kio-extras-data kmenuedit ksysguard ksysguard-data ksysguardd ktexteditor-data kwin kwin-common kwin-data kwin-style-breeze kwin-x11 kwrited libcln6 libdmtx0a libdolphinvcs5 libepub0
  libgps22 libjs-underscore libkdecorations2-5v5 libkdecorations2private5v5 libkexiv2-11v5 libkexiv2-data libkf5activitiesexperimentalstats1 libkf5baloo5 libkf5balooengine5 libkf5baloowidgets-bin libkf5baloowidgets5
  libkf5bookmarks-data libkf5bookmarks5 libkf5dnssd-data libkf5dnssd5 libkf5emoticons-data libkf5emoticons5 libkf5filemetadata-bin libkf5filemetadata-data libkf5filemetadata3 libkf5gpgmepp5 libkf5itemmodels5 libkf5js5
  libkf5jsembed-data libkf5jsembed5 libkf5kcmutils-data libkf5kcmutils5 libkf5kdelibs4support-data libkf5kdelibs4support5 libkf5khtml-data libkf5khtml5 libkf5kiofilewidgets5 libkf5kiontlm5 libkf5kipi-data
  libkf5kipi30.0.0 libkf5networkmanagerqt6 libkf5newstuff-data libkf5newstuff5 libkf5notifyconfig-data libkf5notifyconfig5 libkf5parts-data libkf5parts5 libkf5people-data libkf5people5 libkf5peoplebackend5
  libkf5peoplewidgets5 libkf5prison1 libkf5pty-data libkf5pty5 libkf5runner5 libkf5screen-bin libkf5screen6 libkf5solid5 libkf5solid5-data libkf5su-data libkf5su5 libkf5sysguard-bin libkf5sysguard-data
  libkf5texteditor5 libkf5texteditor5-libjs-underscore libkf5threadweaver5 libkf5wallet-bin libkf5wallet-data libkf5wallet5 libkf5waylandserver5 libkf5xmlrpcclient-data libkf5xmlrpcclient5 libkfontinst5
  libkfontinstui5 libkprintutils4 libkscreenlocker5 libksgrd7 libksignalplotter7 libkwalletbackend5-5 libkwin4-effect-builtins1 libkwineffects7 libkwinglutils7 libkwinxrenderutils7 libkworkspace5-5 liblmdb0
  libokularcore7 libpackagekitqt5-0 libplasma-geolocation-interface5 libpoppler-qt4-4 libpoppler-qt5-1 libpowerdevilcore2 libpowerdevilui5 libprocesscore7 libprocessui7 libqalculate5-data libqalculate5v5 libqapt3
  libqapt3-runtime libqgsttools-p1 libqimageblitz4 libqmobipocket1 libqrencode3 libqt5clucene5 libqt5concurrent5 libqt5designer5 libqt5designercomponents5 libqt5help5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimediaquick-p5
  libqt5multimediawidgets5 libtaskmanager5 libweather-ion7 libxapian-1.3-5 libxcb-cursor0 libxcb-dpms0 libxcb-record0 libzip4 milou okular oxygen-sounds plasma-desktop plasma-desktop-data
  plasma-look-and-feel-org-kde-breezedark-desktop plasma-workspace polkit-kde-agent-1 powerdevil powerdevil-data python3-pyqt5 python3-sip python3-xapian1.3 qapt-batch qdbus-qt5 qml-module-org-kde-draganddrop
  qml-module-org-kde-extensionplugin qml-module-org-kde-kcoreaddons qml-module-org-kde-kwindowsystem qml-module-org-kde-solid qml-module-qtmultimedia qml-module-qtquick-controls-styles-breeze qttools5-dev-tools
  sddm-theme-breeze software-properties-kde systemsettings
Suggested packages:
  rar unrar | unrar-free orion-gtk-theme dolphin-plugins kwin-addons pi gpsd xapian-tools jovie okular-extra-backends unrar python3-pyqt5-dbg xapian-doc
Recommended packages:
  p7zip-full kde-style-qtcurve libkonq-common akregator amarok apport-kde apturl-kde baloo-utils bluedevil cdrdao cryptsetup dragonplayer fonts-oxygen gpgsm gstreamer-qapt gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk3-engines-breeze
  gwenview ibus-qt4 k3b kaddressbook kate kcalc kde-config-gtk-style kde-config-gtk-style-preview kde-config-sddm kde-config-whoopsie kde-telepathy kdeconnect-plasma kdegraphics-strigi-analyzer kdenetwork-filesharing
  kdepim-runtime kimageformat-plugins kio-mtp kmail knotes konsole kontact konversation korganizer krdc kscreen ksshaskpass ksystemlog ktorrent kubuntu-driver-manager kubuntu-notification-helper
  kubuntu-settings-desktop kubuntu-web-shortcuts kwalletmanager kwin-addons libpam-kwallet4 libpam-kwallet5 libqt5qml-graphicaleffects libreoffice-base libreoffice-kde libreoffice-style-oxygen okular-extra-backends
  partitionmanager phonon4qt5-backend-gstreamer pinentry-qt plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-discover plasma-discover-updater plasma-nm plasma-pa plasma-runners-addons plasma-wallpapers-addons plasma-widgets-addons
  plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text print-manager python-qt4-dbus qapt-deb-installer qt5-image-formats-plugins qtdeclarative5-xmllistmodel-plugin skanlite user-manager libkf5emoticons-bin catdoc
  libkf5kdelibs4support5-bin libkf5khtml-bin libkf5parts-plugins qml-module-org-kde-runnermodel libkf5su-bin ktexteditor-katepart kde-config-screenlocker discover | muon-discover fonts-noto kde-style-oxygen-qt5
  kgamma5 muon-notifier muon-updater sddm
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-xapian-index ark baloo-kf5 breeze breeze-cursor-theme dolphin fonts-noto-hinted frameworkintegration ieee-data kde-cli-tools kde-cli-tools-data kde-spectacle kded5 kdoctools5 khelpcenter khotkeys khotkeys-data
  kinfocenter kinit kio kio-extras kio-extras-data kmenuedit ksysguard ksysguard-data ksysguardd ktexteditor-data kubuntu-desktop kwin kwin-common kwin-data kwin-style-breeze kwin-x11 kwrited libcln6 libdmtx0a
  libdolphinvcs5 libepub0 libgps22 libjs-underscore libkdecorations2-5v5 libkdecorations2private5v5 libkexiv2-11v5 libkexiv2-data libkf5activitiesexperimentalstats1 libkf5baloo5 libkf5balooengine5
  libkf5baloowidgets-bin libkf5baloowidgets5 libkf5bookmarks-data libkf5bookmarks5 libkf5dnssd-data libkf5dnssd5 libkf5emoticons-data libkf5emoticons5 libkf5filemetadata-bin libkf5filemetadata-data libkf5filemetadata3
  libkf5gpgmepp5 libkf5itemmodels5 libkf5js5 libkf5jsembed-data libkf5jsembed5 libkf5kcmutils-data libkf5kcmutils5 libkf5kdelibs4support-data libkf5kdelibs4support5 libkf5khtml-data libkf5khtml5 libkf5kiofilewidgets5
  libkf5kiontlm5 libkf5kipi-data libkf5kipi30.0.0 libkf5networkmanagerqt6 libkf5newstuff-data libkf5newstuff5 libkf5notifyconfig-data libkf5notifyconfig5 libkf5parts-data libkf5parts5 libkf5people-data libkf5people5
  libkf5peoplebackend5 libkf5peoplewidgets5 libkf5prison1 libkf5pty-data libkf5pty5 libkf5runner5 libkf5screen-bin libkf5screen6 libkf5solid5 libkf5solid5-data libkf5su-data libkf5su5 libkf5sysguard-bin
  libkf5sysguard-data libkf5texteditor5 libkf5texteditor5-libjs-underscore libkf5threadweaver5 libkf5wallet-bin libkf5wallet-data libkf5wallet5 libkf5waylandserver5 libkf5xmlrpcclient-data libkf5xmlrpcclient5
  libkfontinst5 libkfontinstui5 libkprintutils4 libkscreenlocker5 libksgrd7 libksignalplotter7 libkwalletbackend5-5 libkwin4-effect-builtins1 libkwineffects7 libkwinglutils7 libkwinxrenderutils7 libkworkspace5-5
  liblmdb0 libokularcore7 libpackagekitqt5-0 libplasma-geolocation-interface5 libpoppler-qt4-4 libpoppler-qt5-1 libpowerdevilcore2 libpowerdevilui5 libprocesscore7 libprocessui7 libqalculate5-data libqalculate5v5
  libqapt3 libqapt3-runtime libqgsttools-p1 libqimageblitz4 libqmobipocket1 libqrencode3 libqt5clucene5 libqt5concurrent5 libqt5designer5 libqt5designercomponents5 libqt5help5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins
  libqt5multimediaquick-p5 libqt5multimediawidgets5 libtaskmanager5 libweather-ion7 libxapian-1.3-5 libxcb-cursor0 libxcb-dpms0 libxcb-record0 libzip4 milou okular oxygen-sounds plasma-desktop plasma-desktop-data
  plasma-look-and-feel-org-kde-breezedark-desktop plasma-workspace polkit-kde-agent-1 powerdevil powerdevil-data python3-pyqt5 python3-sip python3-xapian1.3 qapt-batch qdbus-qt5 qml-module-org-kde-draganddrop
  qml-module-org-kde-extensionplugin qml-module-org-kde-kcoreaddons qml-module-org-kde-kwindowsystem qml-module-org-kde-solid qml-module-qtmultimedia qml-module-qtquick-controls-styles-breeze qttools5-dev-tools
  sddm-theme-breeze software-properties-kde systemsettings
0 upgraded, 176 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 96,6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 342 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Comment: If you do the tedious work, you will see that the `no-apt-recommends` packages are a subset of the larger package list. They are not completely different lists.

Comment: Without `--no-install-recommends` you have "0 upgraded, 506 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded." And with `--no-install-recommends` you have "0 upgraded, 176 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded." Makes sense to me. BTW, fix the "6 not upgraded"!

Comment: I think that when that whether or no I add the --no-install-recommends flag, the list of what is recommended should not change. I think that the --no-install-recommends flag should only decide whether the recommended packages are installed. And since it doesn't I want to find out what it does.

Comment: @DKBose, It does not answer my question because the questioner wants to know if the --no-install-recommends flag only install dependecies. I want to know why the list of recommended packages changes when I say that I dont want to install recommended packages.

Comment: As pointed out in an earlier comment, you're seeing a subset. That subset comprises only `dependencies`, not `recommends`.

Comment: There are multiple sets. Without the --no-install-recommends flag, the packages that will be installed is the combination of dependencies and recommends. And if the flag is used, only the dependencies will be installed. But this does not explain why the recommended set changes

Comment: You have recommended packages that do not exist in the Ubuntu Repositories. That does not happen unless you have created a [Frankendebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian). Purge your system of those non-Ubuntu packages and sources, and then the output won;t be as confusing.

Comment: I am using 16.4, this might be the reason that those dont exist in the repos. Im not using any other repo's other than the standard ones and skype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dependency resolution works recursively, so treating recommendations as dependencies will pull in more packages that in turn have dependencies.

So, the list of recommended packages changes because packages recommended by packages that were recommended by a package listed on the command line are no longer included.

This can also cause additional packages to be required, e.g. if one package has a `Depends: xterm | x-terminal-emulator`, another has `Recommends: gnome-terminal`, then resolving without recommendations will not pull in `gnome-terminal`, which would have fulfilled `x-terminal-emulator`, so `xterm` is then required as well if no other terminal emulator is installed.

Comment: If I understand correctly: packages that are recommended when the --no-install-recommends flag used, if those would be installed then some of those would no longer be considered recommended packages because they may be dependencies of each other. And therefore the list of recommended packages may be shorter if the --no-install-recommends is used

Comment: Without `--no-install-recommends`, the `Recommends:` field is ignored, otherwise it is treated almost like `Depends:`, with the exception that if installing a recommended package will cause an impossible situation, the recommendation may also be removed during resolution. The list of recommended packages is any package recommended by any newly installed package, so installing fewer packages causes the list to shrink as well.

Answer (score 11):

Apt has three grades of dependencies:

1. `depends`: This package is REQUIRED. No way around it.
2. `recommends`: This package is optional, but is strongly suggested for full functionality.
3. `suggests`: This package is optional to add additional some additional functionality.

Your Ubuntu system's default settings include `depends` and `recommends` packages (not `suggests`). You can change those settings with the following optional apt flags:

```
  --no-install-recommends
  --install-suggests
```

For a complete discussion of these options, see `man apt-get`.

Comment: The only thing that the man page says is :
--no-install-recommends  
Do not consider recommended packages as a dependency for installing. Configuration Item: APT::Install-Recommends. This not answer my question

Comment: @Whack that's exactly what it does.

Comment: The output from the different commands both have entries in the _Recommended packages_ section. Why would it still have entries when running by default (with recommends) if this is the whole answer?

Comment: “strongly suggested for full functionality” – but sometimes there's a questionable notion of what _full funtionality_ means. For example, TeXLive recommends tons of documentation PDFs, which take up quite a lot disk space yet most users will never use them but instead look up on the internet anyway (if they even need any documentation, and don't just need TeXLive to compile some already-written TeX files).