# How do I install a package without installing the whole group?

Tags: apt, lxdm

I am trying to install the LXDM display manager. In Arch Linux, I use `sudo pacman -S lxdm` and it only installs LXDM. But in case of Ubuntu, `sudo apt install lxdm` is installing the whole LXDE, which is not needed for me. I want to run LXDM with XFCE like I do in Arch.

How do I install only LXDM without installing LXDE?

Comment: What release are you using?

Comment: If you look at https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lxdm you'll see LXDE is not a requirement (some may get pulled in if you allow *recommends* but you weren't specific with your command or any altered options, nor your release; so the requirements may differ for your release)   *LXDM is the LXDE display manager*

Comment: Related: [What does the --no-install-recommends flag do exactly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216892/what-does-the-no-install-recommends-flag-do-exactly)

Comment: Hi, I am actually using Xubuntu 20.04 LTS. Although it uses lightdm, I am not a fan of it. While installing lxdm, it asks to install 49.8 MB package. On my arch, lxdm only adds 0.34 MB. I actually had trouble installing LXDM on Ubuntu server. Even Linux Mint and Rapbian OS also have this issue.

Comment: Actually it's not about LXDM, there are more packages which depends on others that doesn't make sense. For example, while installing Ruby, it installs things like ruby-minitest, libjs-jquery, fonts-lato. I have no idea what fonts-lato has to do with Ruby.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can confirm that running `sudo apt install lxdm` pulls in many dependencies (I tried it in Ubuntu MATE focal but not in Xubuntu, but all focal packages are the same).

After running `apt-cache show lxdm` I see that lxdm `Recommends: lxde-common, desktop-base` and in turn lxde-common `Recommends: lxde-core, lxde-session, lxpanel, lstask, lxrandr, lxsession-logout, lxlock, gnome-screenshot`. Each of these has its own dependencies too, and you do end up installing the entire LXDE.

The solution is to run it like this:

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends lxdm
```

which will result in only single package `lxdm` to be installed.