# How to install gnome 3 on ubuntu server?

Tags: installation, server, gnome

I have installed ubuntu server 64-bit and I want to install gnome 3 or KDE. What dependencies must be installed? Please specify all steps.

Answer (score 7):

The instructions are same as converting a normal server install to a desktop one. Gnome 3 is the default in 11.10, so you can just run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

and be done with it. If you want GNOME shell you'll need to install that too:

- [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

[Another Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65079/just-installed-a-cli-system-then-ubuntu-desktop-does-not-boot-automatically) reports issues with installing ubuntu-desktop on a server in 11.10.

Comment: Additionally, if what the OP meant by GNOME 3 was GNOME Shell, then they can just run the additional command `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` gets you unity.

If you don't want unity, then install either `gnome`, `gnome-shell`, or `gnome-session-fallback`.  These get you the full GNOME3 desktop, a lighter weight version of GNOME, or a look-alike GNOME2 respectively. The last one gives you versions with and without effects.  Each one of those gnome options is based on gnome 3, no matter what they look like.  If you want the real gnome2, then [install Mate](http://complete-concrete-concise.com/ubuntu-2/ubuntu-12-04/ubuntu-12-04-how-to-install-the-mate-desktop).  It is a fork of gnome2 by Linux Mint.  If you want a classic gnome2 look, but based on gnome3 code that isn't gnome-session-fallback, you can [also install Cinnamon from Linux Mint](http://complete-concrete-concise.com/ubuntu-2/ubuntu-12-04/ubuntu-12-04-installing-the-cinnamon-desktop) .

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
sudo aptitude install --without-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

or

```
sudo aptitude install --without-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

for smaller package to download.

Comment: I just tried it on Ubuntu server 12.04 and the parameter is "--without-recommends"

Answer (score 1):

I found this helpful:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg gnome-core gnome-system-tools gnome-app-install
```

[For refer - minimal-gnome](http://www.htpcbeginner.com/install-gui-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-gnome/)